# Kohana - get all Tables by using DB::query

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

How can i recive all tables listet in my database by using `DB::query` in Kohana?
I won't try `mysqli_list_tables` or something like this, because have to find a soultion in the framework.

The next query just give me the current count of the tables inside the database:
`$tablesAvailable = DB::query(NULL, "SHOW TABLES")->execute();`

I need the values, not the integer. You can't use a select statement, because the DB Object expect explicit an table name for executing the query.

The function `as_assoc()` on the result ($tablesAvailable) makes the var to `NULL`. Any ideas so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(Database::instance()->list_tables() as $table)
    {
        echo $table.'<br>';
    }
```